# Use one index as a source of terms in another index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two indexes, one is a list of specific phrases and the other is documents which may (or may not) contain those search phrases.

My indexes looks like the following:

### Phrases

- phrase

### Documents

- creator
- lastUpdated
- documentText

For each phrase in the phases index, I would like a count of the documents within in the documents index, where documentText contains the phrase from the phrases index.

Eg, if the results were to be formatted as a table I'd expect something like this:

```
|   Phrase   | Count of documents |
|------------|--------------------|
| "phrase 1" |                 10 |
| "phrase 2" |                 12 |
```

I can do this with term aggregates within a single index, but can't work out how this might be possible between indexes.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us what your tried / show us what your index schemas look like. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you need help on how to structure your question.

Comment: Good point, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As near as I could tell this just isn't possible with Elastic out of the box. Instead I ended up updating each document to include the related phrases.

To do this, I wrote a small console app which looped through each value in my phrase index and performed a search for that phrase. I then looped through each returned document and added the phrase to a "phrases" property.

I could then do an aggregate query on the set based on that property.